# Wordpress user info link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am piggybacking off of wordpress and creating a front end admin panel for ease of use for people with no Wordpress experience.

I have created a list of users front end and added a link to enable them to go directly to that user within the user edit section of in the backend of wordpress.

I am wonder what the code is to go directly to that user from the code I have already got:

```
    <?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'subscriber',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $subscriber = get_users($args1);


echo '
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Name</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Email Address</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">Telephone Number</th>
    <th style="padding: 10px;">User Info</th>              
  </tr>';

foreach ($subscriber as $user) {
echo '  
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' . $user->display_name .'</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->user_email . '</td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'.$user->tel_number . '</td> 
    <td style="padding: 10px;">'. '<td style='padding: 10px;'><a href='<?php echo admin_url( 'user-edit.php?user_id=' . $curauth->ID, 'http' ); ?>'>Edit Profile</a> . '</td>
  </tr>';

 }
echo '</table></ul>';       
  ?>
```

So as you can see the link is in a table near to the bottom for Edit Info.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_edit_user_link(); ?>">name</a>
```

you can pass the user id for perticular user

```
<a href="<?php echo get_edit_user_link($curauth->ID); ?>">name</a>
```

like this

Comment: When I add in your code it takes ma e back to my index stating the page cannot be found, so the idea is is form my code above it lists all my users in a table by row, at the end of each row I require an edit user link which when clicked (if logged in as my admin) it takes you into the backend to that users profile.php edit page.

Are you able in my code above, to show me an example of what you are advising?

Comment: try to user like this  by passing your user id in this code updated above